# Dynamic SQL from a Dynamic View to Return the field value of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

this function should accept the viewname and return the date on the last record of the view. Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

I call the function in a stored procedure and got this error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

My query:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetLastDate] (@ViewName nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @SQLCommand nvarchar(4000);
   DECLARE @LastTransDate date; 
   SET @SQLCommand = 'SELECT @LastTransDate=LAST(TRANSDATE) FROM' + @ViewName;
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
   RETURN @LastTransDate;
end
```

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to execute Dynamic-SQL from function. You simply cannot do it. Period.

**[`Dynamic SQL in User-Defined Functions`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#UDF)**:

> This very simple: **you cannot use dynamic SQL from used-defined functions written in T-SQL.** This is because you are not permitted do
>   anything in a UDF that could change the database state (as the UDF may
>   be invoked as part of a query). Since you can do anything from dynamic
>   SQL, including updates, it is obvious why dynamic SQL is not
>   permitted.
>
> I've seen more than one post on the newsgroups where people have been banging their head against this. But if you want to use dynamic
>   SQL in a UDF, back out and redo your design. You have hit a roadblock,
>   and in SQL 2000 there is no way out.
>
> In SQL 2005 and later, you could implement your function as a CLR
>   function. Recall that all data access from the CLR is dynamic SQL.
>   (You are safe-guarded, so that if you perform an update operation from
>   your function, you will get caught.) A word of warning though: data
>   access from scalar UDFs can often give performance problems. If you
>   say
>
> SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE dbo.MyUdf(somecol) = @value
>
> and MyUdf performs data access, you have more or less created a hidden
>   cursor.

Consider changing function to stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp_GetLastDate]
  @ViewName SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT MAX(TRANSDATE) FROM' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName);

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand;
END
```

Also keep in mind that `SQL Server` does not have `LAST` function. If you need newest `TRANSDATE` use `MAX()` or `SELECT TOP 1 TRANSADATE FROM ... ORDER BY some_column DESC`

Comment: I tried this method but it is not returning a date variable. The purpose of my query is to accept the viewname and return the max date in that view